# Добавление ng-* директивой

Tags: javascript, framework, angularjs

```
<box>a</box>
<box>b</box>
<box>c</box>
```

Как правильно создать директиву для box, чтобы при клике выводился индекс элемента?

Попытка:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
var indexCtrl = function($scope) {
    $scope.boxes = 0;
};
indexCtrl.$injector = ['$scope'];

app.directive('box', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$set('ng-click','alert(index)');
            attrs.$set('index', scope.boxes);
            scope.boxes++;
        }
    };
});
app.controller('indexCtrl', indexCtrl);
```

В конечном итоге я получаю свой `<box ng-click="alert(index)" index="0">a</box>` но при нажатии ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 1):

Добавленные в функции `link` атрибуты уже не будут интерпретироваться в angular. В версии angular 1.2 можно было бы добавить их в template и использовать опцию `replace: true`. 
В версии 1.3+ опции `replace` больше нет, поэтому вам остается либо добавить `ng-click` на вложенный в box элемент, либо подписаться на событие вручную:

```
 app.directive('box', function() {
     return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           element.on('click', function() {
               alert(attrs.index);
           });
        }
    };
});
```